# Javascript won't work when i change the href

Tags: javascript, php, html

i trying [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2) modal and when i'm try to show it, its only blinking, because it's refreshing..
i'm using this to run it:

```
<a href='index.php?id=".$id."' onclick='showDiag();'>
```

i change the **$id** according to choice of an item in my table

i edited JS a little:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
function showDiag() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onload = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

and later i getting values to modal content via

```
<h2><?php echo "#".$_GET['id']; ?></h2>
etc...
```

**My question is: How i can change "?id=xx" so that javascript worked, to make content dynamically changed in one click?**

Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: becuse you dont stop it the browser treats the link like it would any other link

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options to make the modal work.

- Replace your `href` value with something like `href="#openmodal"`.
- Keep your `href` value as it is and in your `showDiag()` method, add this line `return false;` Also change the `onclick` value to "`return showDiag();`"

For option one, it's straightforward, just replace the `href` value. For option two, below is the working example.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
function showDiag() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  return false;
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href='index.php?id=something' onclick='return showDiag();'>Click here</a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

In case you want to get the href value for some other purposes, you can change your a tag to:

```
<a href='index.php?id=something' onclick='return showDiag(this);'>Click here</a>
```

And then, in your showDiag function, you can get the href value and use it as you need.

```
function showDiag(atag) {
    modal.style.display = "block";

    // Get href value
    var href = atag.getAttribute('href');

    // Use the href as your needs         

    return false;
}
```